# Filter array field in couchbase

Tags: android, view, filter, mapreduce, couchbase

I m working on couchbase lite android.
I have series of documents, every document contains a field which it's value is array of string.
now I want to filter value of this field.

```
{
    type : "customer",
    name: "customerX",
    states: [ "IL" , "IO" , "NY" , "CA" ]
},
{
    type : "customer",
    name: "customerY",
    states: [ "WY" , "CA", "WA" ]
},
{
    type : "customer",
    name: "customerZ",
    states: [  "NY" ]
}
```

I want to get customer documents which have "CA" in their states field.
I m using CBL Android.

```
emit(states , null);
```

then how could I make my Start and End Key option.

```
startkey("CA")
Or
startKey(["CA"])


customerX customerY
```

how can i get only customerX and customerY by "CA" in their states field ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to filter on one state then your best solution would be to make a view like this:

```
 function (doc, meta) {
 if(doc.type && doc.type == "customer") {
   if(doc.states) {
     for (index = 0, len = doc.states.length; index < len; ++index) {
       emit(doc.states[index],null);
     } 
    }
   }
  }
```

This view will emit a view row for each state in the arrays of each of your documents of type 'customer'.  This means that you can then select an individual state with a startkey of "CA" and an endkey of "CA", remember to set the inclusive_true flag to true so that endkeys that match are included:

```
startkey="CA"&endkey="CA"&inclusive_end=true
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What is solution for dynamic SQL we generate, for instance consider a filter form which has all fields that user can filter ( customer name, tel, address, state,...)
in sql world I would generate a dynamic sql condition part by fields that user has filled out.

select *
from x
where [condition1] and [condition2] and [condition3]
conditions are optional and will be concatenate in runtime.
consider the number of options is predefined for example there are only 3 options which can participate in condition part and options are not infinite.
what is the best solution for these kind of situation?